# Printing type parameters in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am wondering if it is possible to extract the type of a type parameter. For example I want to be able to do something like:

```
case list[&T] _: println("list of <&T> type");
```

What I am looking to do is match various patterns that look the same but may have different types and use the specific type.

Is this possible? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `typeOf`, described in [the Rascal Tutor](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Type/typeOf/typeOf.html). A function that prints the type of its argument can be defined as follows (remember to add `import Type;` to your Rascal source file):

```
void printMyType(&T a) { println("<typeOf(a)>"); }
```

Examples:

```
rascal>printMyType(3)
int()
ok

rascal>printMyType("abc")
str()
ok
```

Comment: Duh. I saw that in the documentation but hadn't connected how I could use it. Thanks!